# What does pg_replication_slots.active f for the WAL?

Tags: postgresql, wal

Postgres documentation states the following regarding `pg_replication_slots.active`: `True if this slot is currently actively being used`.

What does this actually imply for a false value?

For example, will the WAL still stick around if the value is false? Can I then set to true and it will continue to replicate from where it left off?

Comment: I guess it's inactive, if the subscription using it was disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all of my personal exploration it appears that even with an `active=False` replication slot:

- The WAL is still pinned and will stick around even if the replication slot is `active=False`.
- It's not possible to explicitly set `active` to `True`.
- Deactivation general occurs because the follower had some issue which made it fail to safely read from the WAL, replicate, and move the LSN pointer.
- Restarting the follower, assuming it then succeeds in safely replicating, will generally fix the issue, and the slot will automatically change to `active=True`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using AWS and because I had automated backups turned off the wal_level was set to minimal and I couldn't bump up the max_replication_slots (even though it looked like I could...). I had to create a new subscriber DB instance and then it worked.